# Swift - How to check if a CAShapeLayer intersects with a button (UIView)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, cashapelayer

Like the title states, I'm having trouble checking if a button intersects with a CAShapeLayer. Right now I have a button that is being moved around via a UIPanGestureRecognizer. When it's let go, I want to check if it's on top of a certain color on this wheel that I have:
[Simulator View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heeWY.png)

The colors are being generated as CAShapeLayers with code like this:

```
let path1 = UIBezierPath()
path1.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 50, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/4 + 0.1, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*3/4 - 0.1, clockwise: true)
path1.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 125, startAngle: CGFloat.pi*3/4 - 0.05, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/4 + 0.05, clockwise: false)
blueCircle.path = path1.cgPath
blueCircle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 143/255, blue: 208/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
self.view.layer.addSublayer(blueCircle)
```

where blueCircle is a CAShapeLayer.

I have code  that checks if my "recognizer" (UIPanGestureRecognizer) overlaps on release that looks something like this:

```
   if recognizer.view!.frame.intersects(blueCircle.frame) {
       print("Blue overlap")
   }
```

but I suspect it always returns false because they aren't in the same "layer". I tried a variety of things including using bounds instead of frames and trying to convert using the center of the gesture recognizer but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Is `recognizer.view!` the button you're talking about? Or is it `self.view`?

Comment: @Sweeper recognizer.view! is the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone running into this issue, I managed to find a solution. It seems that you can call frame on CAShapeLayers but when I checked the print output, it gave me "(0,0,0,0)". I ended up replacing the code that called frame with

```
if self.view.intersects((blueCircle.path?.boundingBox)!) {
    print("Blue overlap")
}
```

so that I'm looking for the path instead and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check intersect with main view (self.view)

You can also tried this

```
- (BOOL)checkViewIntersectsWithAnotherView:(UIView*)selectedView {

    NSArray *subViewsInView = [self.view subviews];// I assume self is a subclass
                                       // of UIViewController but the view can be
                                       //any UIView that'd act as a container 
                                       //for all other views.

     for(UIView *theView in subViewsInView) {

       if (![selectedView isEqual:theView])
           if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selectedView.frame, theView.frame))  
              return YES;
    }

  return NO;
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is going to help. CAShapeLayers aren't views so I wouldn't be able to call this function using it anyways